# Why is ggplot only filling in some of my stacked bars and not others?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, bar-chart, fill

I'm making a stacked barplot using ggplot, but for some reason, it keeps leaving 2 bars unfilled, despite filling in other ones using the same criteria. Why is it doing this and how can I prevent this from happening?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
#Code to replicate

data <- tibble(team = factor(c(rep("Team 1", 10), rep("Team 2", 10), rep("Team 3", 10), rep("Team 4", 10)), levels = c("Team 1", "Team 2", "Team 3", "Team 4")),
               state = factor(c(rep(c("Won", "Tied",
                                      "Rematch", "Postponed", "Forfeit",
                                      "Lost", "Withdrew", "Ongoing",
                                      "Undetermined", "Unknown"), 4)), levels = c("Won", "Tied",
                                                                                  "Rematch", "Postponed", "Forfeit",
                                                                                  "Lost", "Withdrew", "Ongoing",
                                                                                  "Undetermined", "Unknown")),
               count = c(1920, 80, 241, 5, 310, 99, 2, 127, 20, 33,
                         48, 1, 8, 0, 11, 3, 0, 4, 3, 3,
                         140, 5, 8, 0, 17, 2, 0, 5, 3, 7,
                         477, 20, 59, 1, 106, 1, 0, 33, 7, 10))


data <- data %>%
  group_by(team) %>%
  mutate(percentage = round((count/sum(count, na.rm = TRUE)), 2))


data %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill= state, y = percentage, x = team)) + 
  geom_col(position="stack",width = 0.4) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1), limits = c(0, 1)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(percentage, accuracy = 1)), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = .5), 
            check_overlap = TRUE )
```

Here's how it looks; the floating 75% and 59% for Team 3 and Team 2, respectively, should be in the salmon color that is used for Teams 4 and 1. I know it's not a typo because I'm using the same title for each.

[image]

Comment: you could remove at least 60% of this code to make it a bit nicer question to look at (and make it easier for us to find the problem. The less code, the faster we can spot the problem)

Comment: @tjebo, done! Thank you for looking over the question and for the suggestion.

Comment: The rounding error seems to be making ggplot drop the last column. `limits=c(0,1.1)` solves it (or something like that). Edit: @TarJae solution solves it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the position argument to `fill`

```
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill= state, y = percentage, x = team)) + 
  geom_col(position="fill",width = 0.4) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1), limits = c(0, 1)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(percentage, accuracy = 1)), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = .5), 
            check_overlap = TRUE )
```